# why does my threadExecutor calls the same callback twice?

Tags: java, multithreading, callable, executor

i have this code:

```
public <T> T executeCodeBlockWithTimeLimit(String criticalBlockTimeOutMilli, Callable<T> callable) throws
        Exception {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<T> future = service.submit(callable);

    startStopWatch();
    T result;

    if (criticalBlockTimeOutMilli != null) {
        result = future.get(Long.parseLong(criticalBlockTimeOutMilli), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } else {
        result = callable.call();
    }
    long timeElapsed = stopStopWatch();
    e2eResult.runTime = timeElapsed;
    service.shutdown();
    return result;
}
```

and in outer method:

```
    Callable<Void> callable = new
            Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws
                        Exception {

                    System.out.println("22222");

                    return null;
                }
            };
    timerUtils.executeCodeBlockWithTimeLimit(criticalBlockTimeOutMilli, callable);
```

And I see the console prints

```
22222
22222
```

why is this called twice?

Comment: Is criticalBlockTimeOutMilli set to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the **Future** from an **Executor** with the `submit` method this one calls the **Callable** object method and stores the result. In your code you first get **Future** then if the variable `criticalBlockTimeOutMilli` is `null` you call the `call()` method on your Callable object. That means executing twice the **Callable** object.

You should use the `get()` method instead because this one use the already collected result from your **Future** object (see [Future#get() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())).

Comment: but `Future.get` is lazy executor. No? then calling `callable.call` never triggers the first execution (the one from `submit`). No?

Comment: `but Future.get is lazy executor. No?`
This is not a _Lazy Executor_. In fact when you submit a **Callable** object to an **Executor** this one runs it in a **new Thread** and stores the result in a **Future** object ([Executor#submit(Callable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable))).
Indead _Lazy Executor_ would mean that the Callable object is only run when the `Future.get()` method is called.

Comment: `then calling callable.call never triggers the first execution (the one from submit). No?`
This is the **Executor** that launches the `Callable.call()` method (when submitted). You dont need to launch it yourself. If you do it runs the method in the **current/main Thread**.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (criticalBlockTimeOutMilli != null) {
    result = future.get(Long.parseLong(criticalBlockTimeOutMilli), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} else {
    result = future.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If criticalBlockTimeOutMilli is null, then the executor will invoke the callable once, and the

result = callable.call();

will invoke it a second time.

(?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ExecutorService` isn't clear for you, here's the javadoc for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)

When you call `submit(Callable)` the executor service will invoke your callable for you.  There's no need for you to invoke it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming criticalBlockTimeOutMilli, is set to null, you are calling call method twice. One with submit method via executor service as below:

```
Future<T> future = service.submit(callable);
```

And then you call it via call method as below:

```
result = callable.call();
```